# RXSwift Update single element

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift

Considering I have a array of items which might be updated on a different view controller and get notified update the change.
How can I update a `Observable<[SomeObject]>` with a single `SomeObject` modification so the change will then be propagated to the UITableViewController that presets these items?

P.S.
I can load the whole thing again with some hack, but it's obviously wrong for various reasons.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource` from `RxDataSources`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't.

However, if you change your model, there are several ways you can go about doing it. One example is here: https://github.com/dtartaglia/RxMultiCounter

In RxMultiCounter, I populate the tableView with an `Observable<[UUID]>` and track the changes for each item inside an `Observable<[UUID: SomeObject]>`. Updating the latter observable doesn't cause the tableView to reload.